# Application rendering at incorrect size using Flex 4.6 & AIR 3.9 on iOS7

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, air, ios7

I am running into a problem while creating an app where the app is not being rendered at the correct size in iOS7 on an iPod Touch 5G. I have started with a blank "View Based" application using Flex 4.6 and AIR 3.9. The "Home View" is being automatically generated by the "New Project Wizard", and no further setup is being done. I basically was just trying to get my work flow setup so that I could check into SVN, compile to the device, and deploy to TestFlight etc. when I noticed that the blank app was not displaying correctly. I have tested the app on an Android device as well and it fills the entire screen as it should with the same exact setup. I have also ran it on an older iPod Touch and it fills the screen, but I believe that may be because the screen resolution is lower on that device...not sure.

Anyways, I have added a link to a screen grab where you will be able to see a large black area at the top and the bottom of the screen. It seems like it is displaying at a lower resolution, or possibly locking to a certain aspect ratio. However, I would like it to fill the whole screen by default. It just seems like I have never had this issue before creating the same types of apps in iOS6 for the iPhone 5 for example...so I'm not sure whats going on.

[Reference Image - Screen Grab](http://www.millerbrosinteractive.com/dev/screengrab.png)

I guess it's also worth noting that when running locally using the simulator, the entire screen area is displayed as desired, and it does not render black area on the top and bottom of the app. The problem only exists when running the app on the actual device.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support 4" iOS screens, you **must** add a launch image with the name of `Default-568h@2x.png` in the `src` directory of your project.

See [this page here](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html), which notes the requirement.

Comment: Perfect. That sorted me out. Thanks Josh!